# AngularJS Framework with fabricjs

Tags: angularjs, fabricjs

Can anyone suggests me angularjs framework with fabricjs.

I'm going to build angularjs application , having canvas (FabricJS).

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to use angularjs with fabricjs.

The project I'm currently working on uses this combination.
We get a lot of troubles related to scope. E.g. if you need to update something in angular from fabricjs, you need to determine if angular digest loop is currently running and if not, run it.

You could try React + fabricjs instead. React looks more flexible and much faster works with DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In my Angular project (seat reservation system) I use Fabric.js (for seat plan editor) without any complications. I have no problem with displaying more than 1000 objects.

[Here](https://github.com/milanhlinak/hello-angular-fabric) you can find my "Hello World" Angular + Fabric.js project.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42626903/2598453) you can find my answer on question "How to use / include fabricjs in Angular2".

Answer (score 0):

You should not worried about how bind them togheter. Keep it simpe.

Fabric will trigger a series of event from user actions, a bunch of event similar firing function that you can find in your doc. Use those to update your app state.

For all the rest keep a reference of the canvas in you scope and use it normally.