# How to use / include fabricjs in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fabricjs

I want use fabricjs in my project. I installed fabricjs using bower and linked in index.html. but it is not working. Please see the below code.

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
 <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');         </script>
  <title>Image Editor</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
  <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
  <script src="libs/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

  <script src="css/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="css/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  // incuding fabricjs here
  <script src="../../bower_components/fabric.js/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>

  <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->

<body>
     <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

This is component file "stage.component.ts"

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import { ImageService } from '../services/image.service';

declare var fabric:any;
 @Component({
   selector:'my-stage',
   styleUrls: ['./app/stage/stage.component.css'],
   templateUrl: './app/stage/stage.component.html',
 })

 export class StageComponent implements OnInit {
    title:string = 'Image Editor';
    imgpath: string = '';
     canvas:any = null;

   // fabric:any = null;
    constructor(
       private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) {
    //  this.fabric = new fabric();
    }

  ngOnInit() {

     this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fstage', {
        isDrawingMode: true,
        selection: true
      });
  }
}
```

I have search many reference but couldn't find out what is wrong with my. Please advice, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can use fabric.js without the line

> import { fabric } from 'fabric';

loading the script on index.html and declaring the library on the ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var fabric: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  printValue() {
    console.log(fabric.version);
  };
}
```

Out on browser console:

```
1.6.7  app.component.ts:13
```

Answer (score 19):

Modern usage:

1. Install Fabric: `npm i fabric`
2. Install types: `npm i @types/fabric`

[Demo with Angular 5.2.8 and Fabric 2.2.2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/2toad-angular-fabric)

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  canvas: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
    this.canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Hello Fabric!'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can save yourself the pain of installing cairo by installing fabric like this in your package.json : `"postinstall": "npm install --no-optional --no-save fabric@2.7.x"` . it works if you are targeting only browser and not servers. Until fabric decide to make a package dedicated for browser it's the best solution i found.

Answer (score 4):

In this way I added Fabric.js to my Angular project created using angular-cli:

**1) Install [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/download/) on your system.**

Note: Cairo is a system library which powers node-canvas, which Fabric.js relies on. When the installation is complete, you may need to restart your terminal or command prompt before installing fabric.

**2) Install Fabric.js**

```
npm install fabric --save
```

**3) Install TypeScript definitions for Fabric.js**

```
typings install fabric --source dt --save
```

**4) Import fabric in required ts file**

```
import 'fabric';
declare const fabric: any;
```

[Here](https://github.com/milanhlinak/hello-angular-fabric) you can find my "Hello World" Angular + Fabric.js project.

**Other links:**

[Fabricjs website](http://fabricjs.com/)

[Fabricjs docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/)

[Fabric](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric) and [type definitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric)

Comment: hlinak can you please attach the link to library and documentation Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue recently, the following steps resolved it. (angular 2.3.1 + angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.31)

1. Create a file called typings.d.ts under your `src` folder.
2. Put a line of code `declare module 'fabric';` in it.
3. Then you can `import { fabric } from 'fabric';` in your Angular 2 components.

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem, following is my solution.

1. Install fabric

   `$ npm install fabric --save`
2. Generate typings module

   `$ typings install fabric --source dt --save`
3. Put `declare module 'fabric';` at the end of `src/typings.d.ts`
4. Then import `import { fabric } from 'fabric';` in the Angular2 Component.

It is working fine and giving fabric autocomplete suggestions also.

Comment: I got this error while after 2nd step. MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) instal
l Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [E:\office-projects\
image-editing-demo\node_modules\canvas\build\binding.sln]