# Using Fabric.js with Angular 4

Tags: angular, fabricjs

I'm new Angular and Fabric.js. I'm trying to build a UI where users can drag and drop objects onto a canvas and then connect them with lines.

In essence I'm hoping to get the Angular4 drag and drop example from the first link to play well with the Fabric.js canvas found at the second link.

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-drag-drop">Drag and Drop</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://codepen.io/janih/pen/Pqwbpe">Canvas Example</a></li>
</ul>
```

The drag and drop example works but the Fabric.js canvas renders in Chrome as a square box and nothing more.

Steps I've taken:

In tsconfig.json I've set "allowJs": true

My dnd.component.html looks like:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>

<style>
  canvas {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <simple-dnd></simple-dnd>
        <canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

And canvas.js looks like this:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
     var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {selection: false});
     var grid = 50;
     // create grid
     for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
         canvas.add(new fabric.Line([i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], {stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false}));
         canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], {stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false}))
     }
     // add objects
     var rect = new fabric.Rect({
         left: 100,
         top: 100,
         width: 247,
         height: 309,
         fill: '#9f9',
         originX: 'left',
         originY: 'top',
         centeredRotation: true
     });
     canvas.add(rect);
     var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
         left: 100,
         top: 100,
         width: 223,
         height: 167,
         fill: '#faa',
         originX: 'left',
         originY: 'top',
         centeredRotation: true
     });
     canvas.add(rect2);
     var rect3 = new fabric.Rect({
         left: 196,
         top: 334,
         width: 150,
         height: 75,
         fill: 'blue',
         originX: 'left',
         originY: 'top',
         centeredRotation: true
     });
     canvas.add(rect3);
     canvas.renderAll();
  });
 }, 0);
```

Comment: if you don't mind can you please tell how you have achieved this my requirement is similar to yours.

Comment: I used the answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do something similar. Not using exactly the links you provided though. I use fabric js along with canvas and angular4 to drag and drop png-files onto the canvas like this. Component:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'fabric';
declare const fabric: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-preview',
  templateUrl: './image-preview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-preview.component.styl']
})
export class ImagePreviewComponent implements OnInit {

  image: any;
  file:File = null;
  canvas:any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.context = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
      this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { selection: false });
  }

  handleDrop(e) {
    this.file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (imgFile) => {
      console.log(imgFile);
      const data = imgFile.target["result"];                    
      fabric.Image.fromURL(data, (img) => {
        let oImg = img.set({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          angle: 0
        }).scale(1);
      this.canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = this.canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = this.canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
      });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    return false;
  }
}
```

HTML template:

```html
<div
  (dragover)="false"
  (dragend)="false"
  (drop)="handleDrop($event)">
  <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="500" height="500">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: One question if you don't mind...when you import 'fabric' how does your code know how to find the fabric project?

Comment: This works but there are types for fabric  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/fabric i would like to use them :)

Comment: This was some old code, I wasn't too strict with typescript back when I wrote this but you are correct. Types should be used here. Feel free to suggest an edit though :)

Answer (score 14):

What worked for me (2Toad's solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481766/9753985) on Angular 7:

First install fabric:

- `npm i fabric`
- `npm i @types/fabric`

Add the canvas element in your HTML:

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Then in your TS import fabric and create your fabric object :

```ts
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { fabric } from 'fabric';

 @Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

   canvas: any;

   ngOnInit() {
     this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
     this.canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Hello World !'));
   }
 }
```

Comment: Just a note, fabric types should be a dev dependency: `npm i @types/fabric --save-dev`

Answer (score 8):

**fabric.js + Angular 7.x**

For me it works in this scenario:

1. copy fabric.js to some folder, for example to "/assets" and then include it into index.html

```html
<script src="./assets/fabric.js"></script>
```

2. after imports, declare fabric as any

```js
declare const fabric: any;
```

3. create canvas div in angular template

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

4. add **implements AfterViewInit** in your component and move fabric initialization into **ngAfterViewInit** event handler

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
       const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
       const rect = new fabric.Rect({
          top : 100,
          left : 100,
          width : 60,
          height : 70,
          fill : 'red'
       });
       canvas.add(rect);
}
```

Comment: is there a reason to move it to ngAfterViewinit and not ngOnInit ?

Comment: @schehata Yes. Waiting for the HTML rendering.

Answer (score 4):

[angular-editor-fabric-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-editor-fabric-js) is a "drag-and-drop editor based on Fabricjs for Angular v5 with multiple options"

You can use it as insipiration.